# requiring modules from directory

Tags: node.js, commonjs

I'm a bit confused as to how commonjs is working in the node environment. I'm working with a 3rd party library, and their examples show how to access specific modules like this:

```
const {module1, module2} = require('somedir/someotherdir')
```

I understand that it will look for index.js in the directory, but how does it know which modules to load? In the index.js file, I see:

```
module.exports = {
    someError,
    someOtherError,
    yetAnotherError,

    module1,
    module2,
    module3
}
```

How does the require code above know to pull module1 and module2, and ignore module3, someError, someOtherError, yetAnotherError

Comment: This really isn't related to how commonjs works in a particular node environment rather [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which most languages support. Your basically destructuring the modules `somedir/someotherdir/index.js` exports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a programming technique called *destructuring*, introduced with ECMAScript 2015, a.k.a. ES6.

It's basically a shortcut that lets you put an object's properties directly into variables.

A verbose way to write the code, without destructuring, would be:

```
const someobject = require('somedir/someotherdir')
const module1 = someobject.module1
const module2 = someobject.module2
```

So the *require* statement just gives you a plain old JavaScript object, which you then get the *module1* and *module2* properties of.

This syntax is just a short version of doing that:

```
const {module1, module2} = require('somedir/someotherdir')
```

You could also write, for example:

```
const someobject = require('somedir/someotherdir')
const {module1, module2} = someobject
```

When you write a destructuring statement, you decide which properties of the object to save in local variables by putting the name in the curly braces.

If, for example, you wanted to get *someError* and *someOtherError*, you would write it like this:

```
const {someError, someOtherError} = require('somedir/someotherdir')
```

…and to get everything:

```
const {someError, someOtherError, yetAnotherError, module1, module2} = require('somedir/someotherdir')
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: So it's still unclear as to how it skips the other modules. Is it comparing the actual variable names and matching them? How does it know which modules I want and which ones I don't using the simplified syntax?

Comment: "It" doesn't skip any modules, you decide which modules you want to work with by putting their names into the curly braces. I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: Ok, so it does module name matching. That was a bit confusing at first since it almost seems like an anti-pattern, so I'm a bit surprised with that implementation.

Comment: Destructing assignment is just syntactic sugar for binding a set of variables to a corresponding set of values anywhere that you would normally bind a value to a single variable. Most languages including Ruby, ECMAScript and Python have this feature.

Comment: Right, but I don't think those languages match variable names, do they? I can understand something like this [a, b] = [1, 2], but not [a, b] = [a, c] and then only 'a' is applied because 'b' doesn't exist. I would expect 'b' to be assigned to whatever 'c' is.

Comment: Like I said, what the module is *really* exporting is an object, and you use the names of the properties of that object in your destructuring statement

Comment: Correct, unless you unpack a complex type and assign elements/properties to a variable with a different name i.e. `const {a:aa, b:bb} = {a: 3, b: 4}`. `a` becomes `aa` and `b` becomes `bb` respectfully. You can assign default values as well `const {a:aa = 10, b:bb = 4} = {a: 3};`